# Proving the relationship between Weibull and Exponential Density Functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Take $Y$ to be an exponentially distributed with mean $\beta$. I want to prove
that $W = \sqrt{Y}$ where $\alpha = \beta$ and $m = 2$. Note that the Weibull
density function is
$f(w) = \frac{1}{\alpha} mw^{m-1} e^{-w^m / \alpha}, w > 0$

I thought that
$$P(\sqrt{Y} = w) = P(Y = w^2) = \frac{1}{\beta} e^{-\frac{1}{\beta} w^2},$$

But we seem to be missing some relevant terms within the product that would
make it a Weibull PDF. I believe that I'm
missing some steps in my calculus. Any recommendations?

Comment: First of all you are dealing with continuous random variable, so basically you are not talking about $\Pr\{\sqrt{Y} = w\}$. You need to find the pdf after transformation, so you should learn the technique of Jacobian transformation and/or the technique of differentiating the CDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $Y$ be an RV with Exponential distribution, pdf of $Y$ is:
   $$f_Y(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y},\ 0\leq y$$
   and CDF is:
   $$F_Y(y)=\Pr\{y\leq Y\} =1-e^{-\lambda y},\ 0\leq y$$

and Mean or $E(Y)$ is
$$E(Y) = \frac{1}{\lambda} = \beta = \alpha$$

2.We know
$$W=\sqrt{Y}$$
and this is CDF definiiton of $W$
$$
\begin{align}
F_W(w)&=\Pr\{w\leq W\}\\
\\
&=\Pr\Big\{w\leq \sqrt{Y} \Big\}\\
\\
&=\Pr\Big\{w^2\leq Y \Big\} \\
\\
& = F_Y(w^2)\\
\\
& = 1-e^{-\lambda w^2}
\end{align}
$$
so
$$F_X(w)=1-e^{-\lambda w^2}$$

3. Calculation pdf from CDF
   $$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)$$

so

$$
\begin{align}
f_W(w) &= \frac{d}{dw}F_W(w)\\
\\
&=\frac{d}{dw}\Big(1-e^{-\lambda w^2}\Big)\\
\\
&=2 \cdot \lambda \cdot w e^{-\lambda w^2}
\end{align}
$$

and $\frac{1}{\lambda} = \beta = \alpha$ so
$$
f_W(w) = 
2 \cdot \frac{1}{\beta} \cdot w e^{-\frac{1}{\beta} w^2}
$$
and this is Weibull density with $m=2$ and $\alpha=\beta$.